# Como usar a estrutura HARDWARE_INPUT do C++?

Tags: input, jogos

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que simula inputs para jogos. Utilizando a função `SendInput()` do C++. Já consegui simular inputs de teclado a partir da estrutura `INPUT` usando o parâmetro `INPUT_KEYBOARD`, contudo não sei como utilizar o parâmetro `INPUT_HARDWARE` para simular um controle de Xbox, por exemplo. Estou usando a biblioteca `<Windows.h>`. A seguir alguns links que estou usando como referência:

HARDWAREINPUT Structure:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms646269(v=vs.85).aspx

INPUT Structure:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms646270(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sugiro melhorar a qualidade da sua pergunta para obter melhores respostas. Por exemplo, colocar o código da sua aplicação. Saiba mais sobre [MCVE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Não coloquei o código, pois ainda não o escrevi, não sei como usar essa estrutura.

Comment: Pelo que sei é possível fazer o que você quer usando C#. Se quiser pode dar uma olhada nesse emulador e sua source http://www.x360ce.com/  https://github.com/x360ce/x360ce

Comment: pelo que diz a documentação você só pode simular eventos de hardware verdadeiro para mouse e teclado (ou algo que o sistema veja como mouuse e teclado, p. ex.: digitação numa tela touch conta com teclado, um toque numa tela touch conta como mouse)...a estrutura HARDWAREINPUT aparentemente serve para simular um hardware inexistente, virtual....ps: tire a tag C++ porque isso não tem nada a ver com C++